# How to start local Azure Service Fabric Cluster with PowerShell or CLI

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am developing in Azure Service Fabric and there are several times when the Service Fabric is not started for some reason (usually after a reboot). The Service Fabric Manager in the system tray has horrible response time (if it responds at all).

Is there a PowerShell cmdlet or even a cli command that I can use to start the local Service Fabric?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use the `Start-Service` cmdlet

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Start-Service FabricHostSvc
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)' to start...
```

You can also check if the host is running by running `Get-Service`

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-Service FabrichostSvc

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  FabrichostSvc      Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service
```

If it's running you can also use `Restart-Service`

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Restart-Service FabrichostSvc
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabrichostSvc)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service     (FabrichostSvc)' to start...
```

Comment: I am selecting this as the answer because, even though the answer bygrace gives works, this is the root answer. Thanks and sorry for taking so long.

Comment: Get-Service can be run as non-admin. Start-Service must be run in a powershell with admin privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and ended up using the utility functions provided with the SDK which I found here:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1

In my powershell script I use the following to import the utility functions:

```
# Import the cluster setup utility module
$sdkInstallPath = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Service Fabric SDK').FabricSDKScriptsPath
$modulePath = Join-Path -Path $sdkInstallPath -ChildPath "ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1"
Import-Module $modulePath
```

Then I have the following to check if the cluster is running and to start it if it is not:

```
# Start the local cluster if needed
if (-not (IsLocalClusterRunning))
{
    StartLocalCluster
}
```

Under the covers it basically does the same thing that Kevin does in his answer (`Start-Service FabricHostSvc`). So if you are setting up a PowerShell script this may be helpful but if you just wanted to run a command in PowerShell it may be cumbersome to import the utilities.